# Expand float div in front another

Tags: javascript, css, grid

without changing position. I have a second div in front of a first div, when the second div expands it gets below the first div losing its position, i have not been successful trying with css grid, grid-area, grid-column, order, flexbox, grid with float and javascript with insertBefore but this causes an auto scroll in mobile chrome, is there another way to do it using css pure or js without insertBefore for example with toggle?

when B expands it fits under A

[image: moves position]

i want B to hold his position

[image: hold the position]

```
.frame {
    width: 48%;
    height: 400px;
    font: bold 41px roboto;
    color: yellow;
    border: solid 2px black;
    background-color: purple;
    float: left;
            
}
        
input:checked + .frame {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
}

input{
    display: none;
}
```

```
<div class="gallery">
        
        <input type="checkbox" id="a">
        
        <label for="a" class="frame a">A</label>
        
        <input type="checkbox" id="b">
        
        <label for="b" class="frame b">B</label>
        
        <input type="checkbox" id="c">
        
        <label for="c" class="frame a">A</label>
        
        <input type="checkbox" id="d">
        
        <label for="d" class="frame b">B</label>
        
        <input type="checkbox" id="e">
        
        <label for="e" class="frame a">A</label>
        
        <input type="checkbox" id="f">
        
        <label for="f" class="frame b">B</label>
        
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wooddocu/6zeb0adh/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want is for A to move down instead of B, in which case:
example (only works for D at the moment, but all you need to do is duplicate the code for B and F)

https://jsfiddle.net/9fb035rh/

```html
<body class="gallery">
  <div class="pair" id="ab">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a">

    <label for="a" class="frame a">A</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="b">

    <label for="b" class="frame b">B</label>
  </div>
  <div class="pair" id="cd">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">

    <label for="c" class="frame a">A</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="d">

    <label for="d" class="frame b">B</label>
  </div>
  <div class="pair" id="ef">
    <input type="checkbox" id="e">

    <label for="e" class="frame a">A</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="f">

    <label for="f" class="frame b">B</label>
  </div>

</body>
```

```js
document.getElementById("d").oninput = function() {
  myParent = this.parentElement;
  myLabel = myParent.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
  this.remove()
  myLabel.remove()
  if (this.checked) {
    myParent.prepend(myLabel);
    myParent.prepend(this);
  } else {
    myParent.append(this);
    myParent.append(myLabel);
  }
}
```

Comment: ShackER i also tried putting the label and input in pairs without success

Comment: @lumber did you check the demo link above the code?

Comment: the frames have to be independent of each other

Comment: what does "independent" mean in this scenario? Is the problem the presence of the `<div>`s

Comment: yes i checked it, and I have this problem, how can i write information from a database inside the labels, going through them with a for each with php, if they are in pairs?

Comment: This would require removal of the divs, which I do not have a demo set up for yet, but it is possible (hint: `document.body.querySelector("label[for='" + this.id + "']");` finds `myLabel` without using a parent div to classify them)

Comment: ShackER i'm going to study it more